# Excel macro for row-by-row comparisons with row reordering

Tags: vba, excel

this is my first attempt to create a macro, so sorry in advance for my lack of knowledge on the subject. I've attempted to follow tutorials and examples online, but I'm not having a lot of luck.

I want to create a macro that can move an entire row above the previous row if certain values in the row are less than the respective values in the previous row.

I tried posting an image of the excel sheet I'm working with, but I do not have enough reputation.

The logic would be something like this:

IF--- Column2(row_i) < Column2(row_i-1)

AND--- Column3(row_i) < Column4(row_i-1)

THEN

Insert a blank row above row_i-1

Copy row_i and paste it in the blank row

Delete the original row_i

Return to top of list and begin search again

ELSE--- Move to row_i+1}

Here is what I currently have:

```
Sub PrioritySort()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 11 To 17
    If Cells(i, 2) < Cells((i - 1), 2) Then
         If Cells(i, 3) < Cells((i - 1), 4) Then
         //insert row_i above row_i-1
    Else
         Next i
End Sub
```

If anyone would be willing to help, it'd be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

//insert row_i above row_i-1 is something like:

```
Rows(i).Select
Selection.Cut
Rows(i-1).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

...Also remember an "End If" to close out your multiline If statements.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to only cut/insert a portion of a row? Moving the entire row seems to reformat all the equations of the row. I'm using this macro to move a higher priority job above a lower priority job if all workers are busy. I think if I only move a section of the row, the calculations will be correct.

Comment: Would replacing Rows(i) with Range(Cells(i,1),Cells(i,5)) do this?

Comment: @ConnorM.: Yeah, that's correct.

    `Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 2)).Select  \n

    Selection.Cut  \n

    Range(Cells(i-1, 1), Cells(i-1, 2)).Select  \n

    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown`

Comment: my comment above moves only columns 1 and 2, but as you noted, you can do `Range(Cells(i,1),Cells(i,5))` to affect columns 1 through 5, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a sample:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4
4       4       4       4
3       3       3       3
2       2       2       2
1       1       1       1
```

We want to reordering this. Our end result should look like this

```
column1 column2 column3 column4
1       1       1       1
2       2       2       2
3       3       3       3
4       4       4       4
```

**Macro**

```
    Sub Macro3()

        Dim NoOfTimesChanged As Integer

        ' attempt to reorder rows and find out if reordering
        ' was done or not
        NoOfTimesChanged = ReOrderRows()

        ' keep on reording until there is nothing else to reorder
        Do While NoOfTimesChanged > 0
            NoOfTimesChanged = ReOrderRows()
        Loop

    End Sub
```

**Function**

```
    ' Reorder all rows based on certain condition

    ' Returns:  0 or 1 to the caller
    '           0 is returned when no reording was necessary
    '           1 is returned when reordering was necessary

    Function ReOrderRows() As Integer

    Dim ReOrdered As Integer
    ReOrdered = 0

    ' Lets start from row #3 and compare with row #2
    ' Remember that row #1 has headers
    For i = 3 To 5

        ' IF--- Column2(row_i) < Column2(row_i-1)
        ' AND--- Column3(row_i) < Column4(row_i-1)
        If Cells(i, 2) < Cells(i - 1, 2) And _
           Cells(i, 3) < Cells(i - 1, 4) Then

            ' select the current row and cut it
            Rows(i & ":" & i).Select
            Selection.Cut

            ' select the above row insert the cut-rows
            ' making sure the current selection is moved down
            Rows(i - 1 & ":" & i - 1).Select
            Selection.Insert shift:=xlDown

            ' mark this flag to 1 so as to inform
            ' the caller function that reordering
            ' was performed
            ReOrdered = 1

        End If

    Next i

    ReOrderRows = ReOrdered

    End Function
```

Try this out. Note that I have used only 4 rows + 1 header row and therefore the `for` loop goes from 3 to 5. You can change this code as you desire.

Comment: Thanks for your help! What is the purpose of the NoOfTimesChanged loop? will the macro not search row by row if just:

Sub PrioritySort()

Dim i As Integer


For i = 11 To 17
   If Cells(i, 2) < Cells((i - 1), 2) And _
      Cells(i, 3) < Cells((i - 1), 4) Then
        Rows(i).Select
        Selection.Cut
        Rows(i - 1).Select
        Selection.Insert shift:=xlDown
   End If
Next i

End Sub

Comment: Basically what I'm asking is will the macro not search row by row if just the code from the "Function" section is used (without the ReOrdered line)?

Comment: It's a good question. Yes, PrioritySort or ReOrderRows will search row by row but it will do only a single pass. Using my example, row 3-3-3-3 will be moved up and 4-4-4-4 will take its place. Then, 2-2-2-2 will be moved up and 4-4-4-4 will take its place...until 4-4-4-4 is at the bottom. The result of this first pass will end up with 3-3-3-3, 2-2-2-2, 1-1-1-1, 4-4-4-4 in that order. `do while...loop` keeps on doing a pass over those rows until no more reordering is needed. This is similar to bubble sort.